# Socket | Можете дать готовый пример с сокетами?

Tags: python, сокет

Просмотрел куча разных решениях и он с одной стороны помог мне с одной ошибкой, но появилась другая, гуглю уже 30 мин и найти свежий ответ не могу

**Server**

```
import socket
soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
soc.bind(('',8989))
soc.listen(1)
con, addr = soc.accept()

while True:
    data = soc.recv(1024).decode()
```

- OSError: [WinError 10057] Запрос на отправку или получение данных  on
  a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

**Client**

```
import socket
soc = socket.socket()
soc.connect(('127.0.0.1',8989))

soc.send("hello, world!".encode())

data = soc.recv(1024)
```

- ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно
  разорвал существующее подключение

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем коде для **сервера** 2 недостатка:

1. Вместо `socket.socket()` используйте `socket.create_server()`,
2. вместо исходного сокета `soc` используйте сокет `con` (возвращенный методом `.accept()`).

Значит, правильный код будет

```
import socket

soc = socket.create_server(("127.0.0.1", 8989))
soc.listen(1)
con, addr = soc.accept()

while True:
    data = con.recv(1024).decode()
    print(data)                               # чтобы вы увидели какой-то результат!
    con.send(("Received: " + data).encode())  # возможно ответить
```

---

В коде **клиента** только один недостаток — сообщение `"hello, world!"` *не будет отправлено серверу,* потому что

- всякое сообщение в сети нужно закончить символом `\n`, иначе не возможно узнать, что поток байтов нужно отправить (аналогично <kbd>Enter</kbd> после написания команды):

```
import socket

soc = socket.socket()
soc.connect(('127.0.0.1',8989))

soc.send("hello, world!\n".encode())       # <-------------- здесь добавлено \n

data = soc.recv(1024)
print(data.decode())                       # чтобы увидеть ответ от сервера
```

Comment: А реализовать отправку и с сервера как можно? и получать и отправлять если что

Comment: Нет разницы между севером и клиентом пока идет об отправлении и принятии сообщений. Метод `.send()` отправляет из одной стороны связи, метод `.recv()` принимает это на другой стороне той же самой связи.

Comment: Попробуйте например в коде сервера добавить `con.send(("Received: " + data).encode())` (а в клиенте — чтобы вы это увидели — `print(data.decode())`, т.к. `data = soc.recv(1024)` там уже находится).

Comment: Я это добавил прямо в мой ответ. Не волнуйтесь тем, что сервер затем прекратит связь (`ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053]`), напрасно ожидая ответ от вашего клиента...

Comment: да спасибо, я с прошлым уже поиграть успел.

Comment: `ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053]`  - когда вам это не нравится, добавите в сервер `con.close()`.